# Is DEFAULT NULL and 'nullable value without default' completely the same?

Tags: postgresql, datatypes, postgresql-9.6, default-value

```
ALTER TABLE test_table ADD COLUMN a DEFAULT NULL;
```

vs.

```
ALTER TABLE test_table ADD COLUMN a;
```

Both columns will set `NULL` if column `a` is not specified.

As far as I know, if I add a column into a table with a default value in production database, it could lead to trouble rewriting all rows with default value.

Is `DEFAULT NULL` the same?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Not providing any default value or explicitly providing NULL is exactly the same thing for base data types.

Adding a column with a NULL default value, does not require rewriting the entire table. It is essentially only a metadata update for the table.

[Quote from the 9.6 manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/sql-altertable.html#AEN76217)

> If there is no `DEFAULT` clause, this is merely a metadata change and does not require any immediate update of the table's data; the added NULL values are supplied on readout, instead

---

Note that this has changed with Postgres 11.

When you add a column with a static default (e.g. `default 42`) the table won't be re-written either. Only if you provide a "volatile" default (e.g. `current_timestamp`) the table will be re-written.

Comment: The answer is not 100% correct. Adding a DEFAULT NULL will still lock your table while omitting it will not, this is the case with 9.6. We've had a small incident because of that.

Answer (score 10):

**No.** It's not *completely* the same. `NULL` is just the default default (sic!) of data types.

All built-in data types shipped with Postgres 15 have `NULL` as default<sup>1</sup>. But that does not necessarily apply to *all* types. [`CREATE TYPE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtype.html) and [`CREATE DOMAIN`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createdomain.html) offer to set any default, which applies to all table columns of that type unless an explicit `DEFAULT` is set.

<sup>1</sup><sub>Except for one exotic exception: a data type shipped with the information schema and typically not visible in the schema search path:  `information_schema.time_stamp`, which defaults to `('now'::text)::timestamp(2) with time zone`.</sub>

Demonstrating with a `domain` as that's shorter. But the same applies to non-domain data types:

```
CREATE DOMAIN text_x AS TEXT DEFAULT 'X';

CREATE TABLE tbl (
   col_no_default text_x
 , col_default    text_x DEFAULT NULL
);
```

The default value of `col_no_default` is 'X', while the one of `col_default` is `NULL`.

```
INSERT INTO tbl1 DEFAULT VALUES RETURNING *;
```

| col_no_default | col_default |
| --- | --- |
| X | null |

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/-QS2XU3L)